Python: How to move area edge to resize area?
I want to move the PROPERTIES area's edge with python,but it's not working.Here is my code.But it reported error:Operator bpy.ops.screen.area_move.poll() failed, context is incorrect.How can I solve it? Or may I have other ways to move area's edge?
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'PROPERTIES':
       x = area.x
       y = area.y
    context.window.cursor_warp(x+20, y)

    bpy.ops.screen.area_move(x=0, y=50, delta=0)
```

